# Get substring from specific string using vbscript

Tags: regex, vbscript, substring

I'm newbie in VBScript and have a following task:

> Get substring from specific string using vbscript.

**The source string**:

`one two alksdjfkl <b> sdklifjklsdjf </b> <b:FileName>Test</b:FileName> jsdhfj rutyier x,mcvn,mcx </b> <b:FileName>Test2222.docx</b:FileName> mvbn,cmvb eiurtyeiurty`

I need to get content between  and  
I've tried following:

```
Set objRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
Str = "one two alksdjfkl <b> sdklifjklsdjf </b> <b:FileName>Test</b:FileName> jsdhfj rutyier x,mcvn,mcx </b> <b:FileName>Test2222.docx</b:FileName> mvbn,cmvb eiurtyeiurty"
objRegExp.Global = True
objRegExp.Pattern = "^<b:FileName>*</b:FileName>$"
Set objMatches = objRegExp.Execute(Str)
msgbox objMatches.Count
    For i = 0 To objMatches.Count - 1
       Set Match = objMatches.Item(i)
        msgbox Match.Value
    Next
```

But I didn't get what I really need: `Test.doc`, `Test2222.docx`. It seems that I don't understand how regex specific symbols are working.
Could you please help me with this task?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The object [`RegExp` is a built-in VBScript object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//yab2dx62%28v%3dvs.85%29), you do not have to late bind to it using the `CreateObject()` method. the exception to this is if you are accessing it via VBA which can only access it through COM because it exists in the VBScript runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may fix your code like this:

```
Dim str
Set objRegExp = new RegExp
str = "one two alksdjfkl <b> sdklifjklsdjf </b> <b:FileName>Test</b:FileName> jsdhfj rutyier x,mcvn,mcx </b> <b:FileName>Test2222.docx</b:FileName> mvbn,cmvb eiurtyeiurty"
objRegExp.Global = True
objRegExp.Pattern = "<b:FileName>(.*?)</b:FileName>"
Set objMatches = objRegExp.Execute(str)
MsgBox objMatches.Count
For i = 0 To objMatches.Count - 1
    Set Match = objMatches.Item(i)
    MsgBox Match.SubMatches(0)
Next
```

**NOTES**

- `<b:FileName>(.*?)</b:FileName>` is the regex that matches and captures any 0  or more chars other than line break chars between `<b:FileName>` and `</b:FileName>` into Group 1
- To access the Group 1 value, use `Match.SubMatches(0)`.